# Unable to get the updated id value of div eventhough it is adding in the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc7pr.png)I am trying to add multiple divs (containing 2 children h1 and canvas) to a div.

The added div ids are getting added in the HTML but i am not able to get the updated div ids through the api using the JavaScript.

Please find the below code in JavaScript.

Please find the attached screen shot which is showing the issue in detail in the Chrome Debugger

```
    function addElement() {
    var ni = document.getElementById('interview_div');
    var userdiv = createUserDiv();
    ni.appendChild(userdiv);
    var canvas_id = document.getElementById('candidate_div').lastChild.getAttribute('id')
    console.log(document.getElementById('candidate_div').lastChild.getAttribute('id'));
    var canvas_temp = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    context = canvas_temp.getContext("2d");
    drawTimeLine(20);
}

function createUserDiv(){
    var div_user = document.createElement("div");
    div_user.setAttribute('id','candidate_div');
    var abcd = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var firstInput = createInput(abcd);
    div_user.appendChild(firstInput);
    var temp_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    temp_canvas.setAttribute('id' , 'temp_canvas'+ abcd);
    //width="1500" height="40"
    temp_canvas.setAttribute('width','1500');
    temp_canvas.setAttribute('height','40');
    div_user.appendChild(temp_canvas);
    return div_user;
}
function createInput(name){
    var input = document.createElement('h1');
    input.innerHTML = name;
    //input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    //input.setAttribute('name', name+'[]');
    return input;
}
```

Comment: there is no attached screenshot

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot

Comment: Not related to your question that I didn't read carefully enough to understand, but... Wow. you are getting your node in order to get its id attribute to be able to call getElementById ?! Why?